# Javascript problems with moving last child in div

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I have a `simple app` where `cards` are being added `over time` with a `progress bar progression` and when user `clicks` on `moveCard button`, it should `animate` or move the card away. But at the moment when I click on `move card` when it is still `moving` it puts it back where it came from and starts again.

Is there a way to forget the `div` once it has started moving? Because when I try to `delete` it once it has started `moving` it just `dissapears` and that is also not correct.

Here is my `javascript file` and if needed I can add the `fiddle`:

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById("cards");
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
var width;
var id;

//Move card
document.getElementById("moveCard").addEventListener("click", function () {
    myMove();
});


//Start the game
document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
        move();
});

//Stop the game
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    stop();
});

function move() {
    width = 1;
    id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            elem.style.width = 1 + '%';
            clearInterval(id);
            addCard();
            move();
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        }
    }
}


function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("cards").lastElementChild;

    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(movie, 5);
    function movie() {
        if (pos == 350) {
            clearInterval(id);
            elem.remove();
        } else {
            pos = pos + 5;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
    }


}

function addCard(){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.position = "relative";
  div.style.color = "green";
  div.classList.add("card");
  parentEl.appendChild(div);
  sortCards();
}


function stop() {
    elem.style.width = 1 + '%';
    clearInterval(id);
}
```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bfnqmns2/

Comment: Can you please create an `HTML\CSS\JS` snippet so we can also see the bug ourselves?

Comment: @Thatkookooguy added a snippet

Comment: Use a global variable where you reference the last card. When adding a new card update that variable. When moving a card use the value of that variable to get the last card and set it to the previous sibling of the card being moved.

Comment: @JohnCaprez I will try that

Comment: @kataroty would you mind if the animation was handled mostly in `css`? I think you can ditch a lot of the animation code in the javascript + fix this problem. if you think that can be an acceptable answer, I'll write one

Comment: @JohnCaprez actually wait, what if I move a card 3 times in a row before a new one comes.

Comment: @Thatkookooguy since I mostly code in java I do not have that much experience with css but I guess it can work also, unless its hard to understand

Comment: Should not be a problem as each time you move a card you set the variable to the "new last card" until there are no more cards. Do that _before_ you actually move the card so the variable always has the correct card.

Comment: @kataroty I'll answer a bit later and we'll see I guess :-)

Comment: @Thatkookooguy ill be waiting :)

Comment: @JohnCaprez `When moving a card use the value of that variable to get the last card and set it to the previous sibling` i tried but, how exactly do i do that?

Comment: elem.previousSibling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

Comment: Actually I just realized that I am doing it a bit badly, I should still remove the cards from the left side, but add them from right to left not the way they are coming now.